# Adding current URL filename as a class inside a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add the file name (extracted from the URL) into a `div`

Here is my attempt so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var url = window.location.pathname;
var filename = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
filename = filename.replace('.','_');
</script>

<div class="myinterior "<script>document.write("+filename+");</script>></div>
```

The whole script gets rendered literally instead of adding the file name. What am I doing wrong? I can also use jQuery if needed.

Thanks

Comment: Inline JS is a sign of bad coding cause hardly maintainable. document.write is a bad form. Use other methods like `innerHTML = filename` right inside your first `<script>` tags after targeting the selector like you should target one. And that's not hart to find out by using Google or SO's search box.

Answer (score 2):

this is the equivalent of your code in jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var url = window.location.pathname;
    var filename = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
    filename = filename.replace('.','_');
    $('.myinterior').addClass(filename);
</script>

<div class="myinterior"></div>
```

not to mention that you need to include the jQuery library in your HTML and use a `document.ready()` function if you wanna use jQuery!

**the none jQuery answer would be:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var url = window.location.pathname;
    var filename = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
    filename = filename.replace('.','_');
    var elem=document.getElementsByClassName('myinterior')[0];
    elem.className = elem.className + " " + filename;
</script>

<div class="myinterior"></div>
```

Comment: ... or a note to put `<script>` right before the `</body>` tag.

Comment: also `type="text/javascript"` is not needed in the case of JS

Comment: "_I can also use jQuery if needed._". "_if needed_". Is jQuery really needed? Come on Amin, you're better than that!

Comment: @blex I'm so used to jQuery that I can barely remember JS! :) but anyways noted and updated!

Comment: Running `var elem=document.getElementsByClassName('myinterior');` in the console returns "undefined". Is the `getElementsByClassName` a native js function?

Comment: try `document.getElementsByClassName('myinterior')[0];`

Comment: Why are you not correcting the sticking of a `<script>` tag inside a `<div>` tag's declaration? That's not php.... I don't know what you're trying to do.

Comment: @colepanike I meant you can use the inline coding with php codes e.g. `<div class="<?php echo 'className'; ?>"></div>` not with js

Comment: Ahh, ok. Well that's not very clear. You might consider taking it out altogether.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div class="myinterior"></div>
```

JS for modern browsers:

```
var url = window.location.pathname;
var filename = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
filename = filename.replace('.','_');
document.querySelector('.myinterior').classlist.add(filename);
```

Comment: Add this in a `<script>` tag at the bottom of your page before the `</body>` tag.